# jquery doesnt go to error or success

Tags: jquery

Related to this: [How do I connect an autocomplete to a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955828/old-school-net-1-1-app-need-autocomplete-connected-to-textbox)

Im trying to link autocomplete (from jquery ui) to a textbox.
I've got the following:

```
$("#txtTags").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {   
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GetTags.asmx/GetTags",
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(xml) {
               alert("hi");
               // Completion logic goes here
          },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },    
    });
```

Why do I not get either `alert` from the success function or the error function?  I have to use the dataType XML because I am on an ancient `.net 1.1` application json/jsonp was not supported back then (2002/2003).  GetTags.asmx is my web service method.  But of course I do not get any errors nor do I get an autocomplete selection when I type in my textbox.

Update:

Fixed the success issue so I do get to the success function, question is how come my autocomplete textbox still comes up empty?  In my first link posted at the top of this question I am already getting my autocomplete data from the database, I store it as a string array and I return it in my webmethod.  What must I do in jquery to get this data?

### Edit 2

Here is the xml file after I run the webservice (.asmx) file from chrome / ie:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.


 <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/quikfix.jakah.com/GetTags">
    <string>.net</string>
    <string>.net-1.1</string>
    <string>3g</string>
    <string>6283</string>
    <string>7641</string>
    <string>8-id</string>
    <string>80070005</string>
    <string>accounts</string>
    <string>actions</string>
    <string>activation</string>
    <string>active-directory</string>
    <string>active-directory</string>
    <string>ad</string>
    <string>addin</string>
    <string>adp</string>
    <string>adp-tlm-interface</string>
    <string>adptlm</string>
    <string>adupdater</string>
    <string>ajax</string>
 </ArrayOfString>
```

Comment: Have you used a javascript debugger to verify that the `$.ajax` function is called and used a proxy/debugger to see that there actually is an http POST request going out?

Comment: you misspelled `success`.

Comment: @KevinB i fixed that but how come I am still not gettign results in my autocomplete?

Comment: @oJM86o because you aren't passing an array to the `response` method, as noted in the api.

Comment: After spelling it correctly, I see it calls the success function but I still dont see any entries in an autocomplete.  Do I need to do anything inside of success to load the autocomplete?

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, but I am new to this is it possible to help me realize what I am doing wrong.  How do I pass an array to the response method?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: What browser are you using? I know some versions of IE don't like trailing commas. Try removing the one on the second row from the bottom. If that doesn't fix it, do what Lee suggests

Comment: I can test the asmx file within .net and I see the data coming back so its not an issue with the .asmx file.  I just dont know how to fix the jquery code to get the results.

Comment: @KevinB unfortunately kevin, that example takes static strings and assigns them `$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({      source: availableTags    });` for me I am calling the `GetTags.asmx/GetTags` web service.  But I dont see any entries when I type in my textbox.  If I run the web service alone using a link I see the returned results.

Comment: @ojm86o then you looked at the wrong example.

Comment: @KevinB I looked at the jsonp one but still my lack of understanding this make it difficult :(.  Is there any way you can look at what I have above and show me what to pass to response?

Comment: @oJM86o I can't because **you** have to parse the xml into an array.

Comment: @KevinB I thought I got the data back as an array of strings, see my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955828/old-school-net-1-1-app-need-autocomplete-connected-to-textbox

Comment: At this point you are getting back an XML Document.

Comment: @oJM86o can you post your returned `xml`

Comment: @MohammadAdil I posted it at the top of my answer.  Also Kevin B I guess what was the point of my code in the other link if its still an XML file?

Comment: @oJM86o I don't understand what the point of your other question is to be honest.

Comment: Kevin you mean in the other stackoverflow link?  That one shows the .asmx file code.  So I am pulling this data to load the autocomplete.  That was the reason for that post, but as mentioned I am getting this xml file (that I posted above) that shows the data I want stored in my autocomplete.  But now I'm not sure how to take that and add it in the jquery to load the autocomplete textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create array out of your xml and pass it to the response like this -

```
 success: function(xml) {
    var data = [];    
    $(xml).find('string').each(function(){ 
         data.push($(this).text());
    });
    response(data);
},
```

Comment: EXACTLY what I needed thank you for your time and patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

When using a function for the source option, you must eventually pass an array to the response method.

```
source: function(request, response) {
    ...
        response(thearrayofdata);
    ...
}
```

Comment: right but using my existing code what is `thearrayofdata`?  How do I add that to my code?

Comment: It's the data from your ajax request... Take the xml, convert it into an array, and pass it to response.

Comment: Kevin see my other link old school .net (1.1) app need autocomplete connected to textbox it already takes the data as an array of strings.  Here is the link: old school .net (1.1) app need autocomplete connected to textbox

Comment: Here was my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955828/old-school-net-1-1-app-need-autocomplete-connected-to-textbox

Comment: I will upvote you for helping but I am still stuck :(.

Comment: I have posted the returned result of my `GetTags.asmx` file in the answer above.